# How to select only certain sections from a tab-delimited file to put into a Database using sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, database, select, sqlite

I have a tab-delimited file that I need to only select certain columns from it to populate a database using the sqlite3 module in Python. So in my file I have the vertical line symbol "|" and in other cases a column is empty (I tried showing those empty fields by using the space many times but it doesn't show, so just keep in mind that sometimes some fields can be empty instead of having a number). So for example here are some rows of how the file looks like:

78    |    43     |    texret    |    453    |    4321    |    32    |    433    |
20    |    291    |    texttt                                     372    |    228    |    19    |    999
121   |    46     |    textee    |    3882    |   322    |    432    |    63    |

You can see the rows (which need to be treated as one row of the file) take up two lines.

I would only like to put in the new database that I will build using sqlite3 the 2nd field (e.g. from the first row is number 43), the text field (i.e. the 5th field in my understanding), and the 13th field (e.g. from the same row is no. 433). So this is what I have in terms of my code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('database_1.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Number10(address_no INT, area TEXT, street_no INT, PRIMARY KEY (address_no))')
for line in open('my_tab_text.txt', 'r'):
    fields = line.strip().split("\t")
    address_no = fields[2]  
    area = fields[4]
    street_no = fields[12]
    data = [row for row in fields]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Number10 (address_no, area, street_no) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (data))
con.commit()
```

So from the above code, when I run it I get the error:
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 14 supplied. In other words, it counts in the "|" symbol in as well. I don't know how to work around it. I even tried substituting this line with: 
    fields = line.strip("|").split("\t")

But it still gave me a ProgrammingError but with less number of fields supplied.

The expected output would be to create a database named as "Number10.db" and it would look like this:

address_no    area    street_no 
   78         textret    433
   20         textttt    19
   121        textee     63

So please notice that there are some rows that have empty fields at certain times. I guess, I would need to put a default  value of 0 there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But... you carefully select `address_no`, `area` and `street_no`, then create a new variable `data` which ignores those and is just a copy of every field in the row.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand very well what your answer says. Would you mind rephrasing it. Thanks

Comment: Well, how are you expecting those variables to get into the SQL statement? The thing you're passing into the query is the `data` variable, which you've defined as `[row for row in fields]` - ie an exact copy of the row itself. So you've ignored those three variables, and just passed the whole row into the query.

Comment: Oh I see. So how should I rewrite my data variable? I am very new to sqlite3 and couldn't find anywhere else any help. Would you mind helping me out further?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `data = [row for row in fields]` (a list containing all fields), you want to create a list (or tuple) containing only the rows you want:

```
data = (address_no, area, street_no)
```

then pass `data` in as you have done.

Comment: @ben_nuttail: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense. I tried that and now I get an IndexError: list index out of range. Did I miscalculate my  fields[?]? I tried other indexes but I still  get and IndexError. Any clues? I will keep trying in the meantime. I even though of doing something with the SELECT of sqlite3, but your answer seems more efficient and straight forward.

Comment: What are you getting an IndexError on? Maybe remove the brackets around (data)

Comment: address_no = fields[2] IndexError. I tried putting other numbers but still gives me that the list index is out of range. I also removed the brackets around data, but still is the same. Do you think it has to do with "|" or with some fields being empty? The script creates the database (with three columns) but there is no data in the columns. :(

Comment: Try printing them to see what's there. Maybe there's an empty row?

Comment: Hi. I tried printing them and from what I understood the way it is splitting the rows is not correct. I will try regex to see if it helps. Thank you for your input and the ideas.